# How to create sliding images on hover with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want the images to slide when I move my cursor over the image. Let's say I will have 3 pictures.
The images will slide only if I am on the DIV.
I am pretty sure that this could be achieved with carousel but I am not sure if it is the best way.

My code

```
    <div class="container products">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!-- Reveal Up Full -->
                    <div class="image revealUpFull">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/360/180/technics/1" class="img-responsive"/>
                        <span class="title">Caption <br / ><br / > with some more info</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!-- Reveal Up Full -->
                    <div class="image revealUpFull">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/360/180/technics/2" class="img-responsive"/>
                        <span class="title">Caption <br / ><br / > with some more info</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!-- Reveal Up Full -->
                    <div class="image revealUpFull">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/360/180/technics/3" class="img-responsive"/>
                        <span class="title">Caption <br / ><br / > with some more info</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbbNPM

Also I want the div to be clickable when my mouse is over.

Comment: When you say slide, do you mean left to right?
And if by clickable, you mean linked, you can wrap your .revealUpFull divs in <a> tags.

Comment: Yes I meant left to right just like caraousel. But I want to use something simple. It could create some problems to use caraousel and captions at the same time. So just need simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am pretty sure that this could be achieved with carousel but I am
>   not sure if it is the best way.

Why not? Because of you already use Bootstrap you should use its features in the first place.

also read http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel and find out that you can use multiple carousels on the same page:

> Carousels require the use of an id on the outermost container (the
>   .carousel) for carousel controls to function properly. When adding
>   multiple carousels, or when changing a carousel's id, be sure to
>   update the relevant controls.

Cause you want to slide the carousal on mouseover(hover) you do not need any control, each of your carousels can code like that shown below:

```
           <div class="col-md-4">
                <!-- Reveal Up Full -->
                 <div id="carouse1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                   <div class=" carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                     <div class="item active image revealUpFull">
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/360/180/technics/1"></a>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">>Caption <br / ><br / > with some more info</div>
                     </div>  
                     <div class="item image revealUpFull">
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/360/180/technics/2"></a>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">>Caption <br / ><br / > with some more info</div>
                     </div>  
                     <div class="item image revealUpFull">
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/360/180/technics/3"></a>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">>Caption <br / ><br / > with some more info</div>
                     </div>  
                    </div>  
                   </div>
            </div>
```

Notice that i'm not sure why you wrap your 3 `md-4` columns in a `md-12` column, you do not need a `img-responsive` class for your carousel's images.

After creating your HTML you should create a JavaScript trigger for the mouseover (i use mouse enter here):

```
<script>
    $('.carousel').on('mouseenter',function(){ $( this ).carousel('next');})
</script>
```

> Also I want the div to be clickable when my mouse is over.

As you can see in the above i have wrapped the images in a `a` tag. The only possible issue left will be that the `.carousel-caption` is not clickable and overlay the images. Use the following CSS code to make the `.carousel-caption` clickable:

```
  <style>
    .carousel-caption {
    pointer-events: none;
    }
  </style>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/bmLVbymbhj

**update**

> 1. The caption doesn't slide up anymore. Actually code has changed dramatically. I think I > need to integrate it to your code.

Yes, you should integrate the `revealUpFull` class. Let me know if you found any troubles by doing this, or formulate a new question on SO.

You should use something like that shown below:

```
    .carousel-caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;

    /* make image clickable */

    pointer-events: none;

    /* override bootstrap */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* REVEAL UP FULL */

div.image.revealUpFull .carousel-caption {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -150px;
}

div.image.revealUpFull:hover img {
    top: 0;
}

div.image.revealUpFull:hover .carousel-caption {
    bottom: 0;
}  



    .carousel-caption {
    pointer-events: none;
    }
```

> 2. The left and right arrows which helps to slide are removed. This is what I want but 
>      their blocks remains. So there is a space on the left and right.

I expect that the above issue is not related to the removed arrows but will be due to the size of the images. You are using image with a 360px width. As mentioned before the carousal's images are responsive by default. The CSS code sets a `max-width:100%` for these images, which means that they should not display larger than their original size. You can solve this by using larger images or give the image a with of 100% (mostly scaling up  images will have quality issues). You can use the code that shown beneath:

.carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
max-width: none;
width: 100%;
}

> 3. What I want is when my mouse is over the DIV, 3 pictures will slide automatically with 
>      infinite loop. Between each of them there will be 2 secs

<strike>In fact you should be able to use the following:</strike>

```
$('.carousel').on('mouseenter',function(){ $( this ).carousel('cycle',{interval:2000});});
$('.carousel').on('mouseleave',function(){ $( this ).carousel('pauze')});});
```

But the carsousel already pause on mouseenter. I will post a solution for that later on.

The carousel api has a `pause` option (hover by default), you can set this option to an empty string to prevent the carousel stop cycling on hover.
You should remove the carousel data-attribute in your HTML to enable  explicit JavaScript initialization:

> The data-ride="carousel" attribute is used to mark a carousel as animating starting at page >load. It cannot be used in combination with (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript >initialization of the same carousel.

After that you can use:

```
    $('.carousel').on('mouseenter',function(){ $( this ).carousel({interval:2000,pause:''}); });
    $('.carousel').on('mouseleave',function(){ $( this ).carousel('pause'); });
```

When putting above three point together you will get something look like that show in the following demo: http://www.bootply.com/acGNORR3it

Comment: This is quite close to what I want but there are some things missing. 
1. The caption doesn't slide up anymore. Actually code has changed dramatically. I think I need to integrate it to your code.
2. The left and right arrows which helps to slide are removed. This is what I want but their blocks remains. So there is a space on the left and right.
3. What I want is when my mouse is over the DIV, 3 pictures will slide automatically with infinite loop. Between each of them there will be 2 secs.

I am pretty sure that this could be achieved by editing this code. This will be a good start for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we don't need carousel for this simple feature. Javascript way will be easiest and fastest.

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var i = 0; var path = new Array(); 

// LIST OF IMAGES 
path[0] = "http://lorempixel.com/750/375/sports/1/"; 
path[1] = "http://lorempixel.com/750/375/sports/2/"; 
path[2] = "http://lorempixel.com/750/375/sports/3/"; 

function swapImage() { document.slide.src = path[i]; 
if(i < path.length - 1) i++; 
else i = 0; setTimeout("swapImage()",3000); 
} window.onload=swapImage;

</script> 

<img height="200" name="slide" src="" width="400" />
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emmqYJ

Let me know if any easier solution exists.